# Abbreviating values of chart in tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using column chart where I have data in thousands and I want to abbreviate the data in the tooltip like if it is **35100** so it should be like **35.1k** but it should be in the tooltip.
I have my tooltip options like this...

```
tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
      pointFormat:'<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                  '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
      footerFormat: "</table>",
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true
}
```

I also write a method from which I am getting the abbreviated value.

```
SI_prefixes : any = ["", "k", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"];

abbreviateNumber(number){
    var tier = Math.log10(number) / 3 | 0;
    if(tier == 0) return number;
    var prefix = this.SI_prefixes[tier];
    var scale = Math.pow(10, tier * 3);
    var scaled = number / scale;
    return scaled.toFixed(1) + prefix;
}
```

How to get this type of abbreviated value formatted like **35.1k**, **56.8M** etc in the tooltip? How to use this method with the point value in the tooltip?

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: @pooyan how to get the abbreviated value in the tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of what you have used, you can use `formatter` function like the following so that you can use your `abbreviateNumber` function:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        var s = "<span style=\"font-size:10px\">" + this.x + "</span><table>";

        $.each(this.points, function () {
            s += "<tr><td style=\"color:"+ this.series.color+";padding:0\">"+ 
               this.series.name +": </td>" +
              "<td style=\"padding:0\"><b>"+ abbreviateNumber(this.y) +"</b></td></tr>";
        });
        s +=  "</table>";
        return s;
    },
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
}
```

Here is more information about [ToolTip Formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)